# What does the parameter do for the if statment?

Tags: php, mysqli, echo

What does this loop do? I don't know what it means. I've already tries using the internet to find out what the parameter does but I couldn't find anything.

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Table Game Table created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Comment: Check the bool value for an insert query into a database ?

Comment: It's not a loop, though. But what it means is that if you can successfully query that SQL-statement, it's `true` (first echo is output), otherwise it's `false` (second echo it output).

Comment: thats saying if a mysql query has been executed successfully echo created else show me the error

Comment: it's a conditional statement http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php

Answer (score 2):

Functions like `mysqli_query` return a value, in this case a `boolean` which is either `0` or `false (0)` if it fails to execute properly (Its like your fridge has a function too, you put in milk and cold milk is returned but fails to do so if the outlet is not plugged in) and returns an `object` if it executed properly.

The thing with querys is that we always want to verify if a query is successful or not.

```
if(true){
  # execute this code
} else {
  # otherwise execute this block of code
}

if(($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) != false){ #Translates to: If $result is not equal to false execute the following code.
  # use $result here to print out data.
} else {
  # failed the query cause $result equals to false.
}
```

Its programming logic 1:1, instead of trying to figure out what that function does try to do some basic stuff in the language first.

Comment: From the manual: *Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.* ([source](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)) - meaning that it won't always be a boolean, it might be an object of a mysqli-result. Although `if (mysqli_result_object)` is `true`, just wanted to point out that it's not always a boolean `true`.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it when I just posted. I wanted to explain the basics of functions and classified `mysqli_query`as one of them while obviously it is not.